# Error after android studio Installation?

Tags: android, haxm

I got this problem when installing android studio ? Although the program runs OK ! But what is the use of HAXM, what if I did not enable INTEL VT -x ?

[image: Picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But what is the use of HAXM

It enables the use of the Android x86 emulator images, which run significantly faster than the ARM emulator images.

> what if I did not enable INTEL VT -x ?

You will not be able to install or use HAXM. As a result, you will be limited to development using the ARM emulator images, actual Android devices, and possibly third-party emulators (e.g., Genymotion).

Comment: Thank you for the information, but How can I enable INTEL VT -x ? I am using Lenovo U410, Windows 10.

Comment: @SujanRajShrestha: Ask Lenovo. Usually, it involves rebooting your computer and going into the BIOS settings. Depending upon your CPU, VT-x may or may not be available.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if it's already enabled by trying a few commands.
Start with
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
VT-x must be enabled for hypervisor to run, and hypervisor has to be off for HAXM to run so by trying to turn it off, you can possibly do 2 things at once.
You can also try installing HAXM and it will tell you if disabled.
You can also check your CPU capabilities by looking it up at https://ark.intel.com or getting the Intel CPU ID utility at http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/processors/processor-utilities-and-programs/intel-processor-identification-utility.html

Answer (score -1):

You doesn't have to use AVD which comes with Android Studio, you can try third party AVD, such as [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) or [Bluestack](http://www.bluestacks.com/). Genymotion is the one that I prefer.

Comment: @ Daniel Tah: Thank you ! Everything is solved now :)